# Выбор архитектуры: толстый/тонкий клиент, ставить ли локальный сервер в филиале

Tags: алгоритм, архитектура

Описываю простейший алгоритм выбора архитектуры (верхнего уровня) программного средства, т.е. нужно выбрать:

- тонкий клиент
- или толстый клиент
- сервер нужен
- сервер не нужен

Характеристика объектов автоматизации: Объекты автоматизации находятся в разных городах. Качество канала связи между ними непонятна: может быть хорошей, плохой (вообще отстуствовать). Внутри объекта автоматизации локальная сеть может быть плохой или отличной. Количество пользователей на объекте автоматизации от 2 и более. Размеры передаваемых файлов пока не понятно

Посмотрите пожалуйста мой простейший алгоритм, посоветуйте пожалуйста что требуется изменить в алгоритме и почему?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Случаи локального канала плохого качества достаточно редки в моей практике (а я работал на алюминиевом заводе где фонило дай боже и компы были в экранированных от магнитного излучения и пыли корпусах), в большинстве случаев гораздо проще оторвать руки подрядчику. Вай-фай, витая пара да и оптика не так дорого стоит — всегда есть варианты, как снизить эти риски. (В не то чтобы исключениях но особняком стоит розница, где кассы с терминалами приёма карт visa/mastercard подключены абы как и это вполне терпимо)

Поэтому я бы совершенно спокойно выкинул бы эту ветку в вашем алгоритме выбора.

А вот плохие каналы между офисами — да, это вечная головная боль и не только для России. Дело в общем-то быть не только в том, что канал медленный (диалап), но он может быть нестабильным (ужас-ужас) или тупо может быть трафик дорогим.

И вот тут мы подходим вот к какому вопросу: стоит ли ставить сервер в филиале? Здесь следует задать один важный вопрос: требуется ли обеспечить одновременную работу с одними и теми же данными из разных филиалов или нет? Если у вас каждый офис варится в основном со своими клиентами (условно: клиенты из Европы ходят на европейский сервер, новосибирские - на новосиб, а США и Мексика - на калифорнийский сервер) и особо не пересекаются -- то у вас гораздо меньше головняка на уровне протоколов обмена разгребать ошибки "кто первый тронул данные", "чьи изменения имеют приоритет" и т.п.

Менее значимый вопрос, но тоже можно отразить: как часто в хэдофисе хотят видеть свежие данные по филиалам, готовы ли они терпеть до следующего операционного дня или нужно видеть моментальные срезы. (И вот тут нужно подходить к оценке объёмов трафика синхронизации и ваших каналов до филиалов)

В целом. У вас выбран крайне неудобный вариант представления алгоритма. Вы захотели на одной схеме отразить всё. Не, ну чё -- смотрится внушительно, можно дополнительные деньги брать ;) Но вообще-то я бы ставил во главу угла простоту понимания и исходя из этого сделал бы две отдельные схемы. Первая бы отвечала на вопрос "нужен ли сервер в филиале", а вторая отвечала бы на вопрос "тонкий или толстый клиент".